# how to display video in landscape mode at the start of the application means after launching

Tags: objective-c, ipad

how to display video in landscape mode at the start of the application  means after launching

Comment: I guess you are talking about iPhone programming?

Answer (score 0):

In your applications .plist settings file you can specify which orientations your application supports. If you only require you application to show video in horizontal right after start the you specify:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

Also I believe that iOS versions over 3.1 allows you to use something like:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```